# Cycling through possible indentations in python.el in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

The latest version of Emacs (e.g. `24.3.93.1`) come with `python.el`. How can I cycle through different levels of indentation for a given block?

For instance in the code:

```
for ix in range(10);
   line1
   line2 # <- two possible values of indentation for this line
```

The [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgrammingWithPythonDotEl) doesn't seem to provide info on this and I couldn't find anything on `C-h m`. Is this functionality supported?

Comment: You can get information about the current major mode with <kbd>C-h m</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-h m</kbd> in order to know that. It invokes the `describe-mode` function.

You can also look at the python.el file and look for `define-key`:

```
;; Indent specific                                                                                                                         
(define-key map "\177" 'python-indent-dedent-line-backspace)                                                                               
(define-key map (kbd "<backtab>") 'python-indent-dedent-line)                                                                              
(define-key map "\C-c<" 'python-indent-shift-left)                                                                                         
(define-key map "\C-c>" 'python-indent-shift-right)                                                                                        
(define-key map ":" 'python-indent-electric-colon)
```

Or `indent`

```
;; Indentation: Automatic indentation with indentation cycling is                                                                              
;; provided, it allows you to navigate different available levels of                                                                           
;; indentation by hitting <tab> several times.  Also when inserting a                                                                          
;; colon the `python-indent-electric-colon' command is invoked and                                                                             
;; causes the current line to be dedented automatically if needed.
```

Comment: Thanks -- I am looking at it, but don't see any specific command to cycle through indentations. Is this supported by `python.el` ?

Answer (score 3):

Both python-modes use <kbd>TAB</kbd> for cycling. Should <kbd>TAB</kbd> not cycle, check your init resp. consider filing a bug-report.

BTW the way it's done differs slightly: from outmost position python.el will dedent immediatly, while first hit at python-mode.el from correct outmost position does nothing. Second <kbd>TAB</kbd> at python-mode.el will jump to column 0, then stepping up indent by indent. Python.el does the inverse, steps down indent by indent, but jumps to outmost from column zero.